# zero a.e implies lebesgue integral is zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove that if $f$ is an extended-real value function that is measurable, and $f$ is zero almost everywhere, it is then Lebesgue integrable, and $\int f d\mu =0$.

I am struggling with finding a simple proof for this. The issue is that the set where the function is non-zero might be uncountable, so I can't see how to apporximate it with simple functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \{x : |f(x)| > 0\}$. Then $A$ has measure zero. Any nonnegative nonzero simple function $s$ satisfying $s < |f|$ must be zero everywhere in $A^c$ and therefore must be of the form
$$s(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} s_n \chi_{S_n}$$
where the $s_n$ are nonzero and $S_n \subseteq A$. Therefore, each $S_n$ has measure zero, and so
$$
\int s(x)\ dx = \sum_{n=1}^{N} s_n \int_{S_n} \ dx = \sum_{n=1}^{N} s_n\ m(S_n) = 0$$
Since $\int |f|$ is the supremum of all integrals of nonnegative simple functions satisfying $s < |f|$, we have $\int |f| = 0$, which implies that $\int f = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the set is uncountable, it will have measure 0, because $f=0$ almost everywhere. Therefore while evaluating the Lebesgue integral, you can exclude that set.